# Remove item from jQuery Mobile controlgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a control group with some buttons in it. Now I want to remove a button at runtime.

```
<div id="buttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <button id="btn1">Do 1</button>
    <button id="btn2">Do 2</button>
    <button id="btn3">Do 3</button>
</div> 

$('#btn1').remove();
```

But this doesn't work. I can hide it using `$('#btn1').button('disable');` but that is not I'm looking for.

There is no error. Underwater the button is in fact removed but the wrapped span and div remain...

Here is the actual html that gets created:

```
<div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" id="buttons" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
        <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="c" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-fullsize ui-btn-block ui-corner-left" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Do 1</span>
            </span>
            <!-- here button is gone, but not remaining div/span litter -->
        </div>
        <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="c" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-fullsize ui-btn-block" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Do 2</span>
            </span>
            <button id="btn2" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">Do 2</button>
        </div>
        <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="c" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-fullsize ui-btn-block ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Do 3</span>
            </span>
            <button id="btn3" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">Do 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how to do this?
http://jsfiddle.net/NVbjr/1/

Comment: what error do you get? you can also try to hide it

Comment: your jsfiddle link has nothing related with the question

Comment: @rahul: hmm I used a link from someone else and editted, but this didn't work I see.

Comment: can you tell us what kind of error message your are getting

Comment: I don't get a error message, the button just doesn't disapear. (Added correct jsfiddle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add/remove elements in a jQuery Mobile navbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285869/how-do-i-add-remove-elements-in-a-jquery-mobile-navbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the element in the event handler 'pagebeforecreate'.

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function(){
    $('#btn1').remove();
});
```

Else if you want to remove it later events. You can do in other way.

```
 $(document).bind('pageshow', function(){ 
     $('div[data-role=controlgroup]').children().each(function(index, value){
        if(index === 0) {
           $(value).remove();
        }
     });
 });
```

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49735179/Stackoverflow/buttonGroup/test.html

Comment: You cant call methods on a controlgroup prior to initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/NVbjr/2/

Because you were not firing this in the correct order. You had the fiddle 'onload' when it should not have been. iirc jQuery mobile is funny with it's load sequence. I moved this to nowrap (body) and everything works.

Comment: Great, how do I this in my html page? (instead of jsfiddle)

Comment: From your additional information It would appear to me this is because jQuery mobile loads AFTER jQuery's load method (again iirc, it's been a while since i've used jQM)

Comment: You include the script just before the </body> tag instead of the head. and remove all of the $(function(){ and $(document).ready( junk

Comment: I test it out and it works. But it messes up the rest of my page with loading :(

Comment: Better to use the proper loading method then, check the docs.

Comment: Calls to .button('disable'); mess it up.