# Add buttons into listview dynamically using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a code in jquery mobile that will add buttons dynamically in a listview. The problem is that when I add a button on listview dynamically the style of the button disappears.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/eLENj/98/

I've tried to use the .button("refresh") but doesn't work.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use trigger("create")

http://jsfiddle.net/eLENj/101/

Read more:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Comment: @Jasper, the reason it works is because you are triggering the internal event that causes the widget to be instantiated in the first place.  The jQuery Mobile javascript source isn't terribly complicated to read. :-)

Comment: New read more link: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.php