# dynamic jQuery Mobile injection and knockoutJS

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

At first thanks to all that read my question.

I'm quite new to jquery JQM and knockoutJS and have some problems with a dynamic generated html code.

So I have the following example: I start my app with startPage.html where i load all the scripts(jquery, jqm, knockout) and with a link i go to secondPage.html where i want to load a dynamically generated array of checkboxes.

Now the problem is that i get the checkboxes but i don't have the jqm style for them.

My Code looks like this:

startPage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" `"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>start Page</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="knockout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app/VM/WelcomeVM.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app/VM/CheckboxVM.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 //javascript code 
 var master = null; 
 var masterVM = function(){
     var startVM = new welcomeVM();
     var checkBoxHandler = new checkBoxVM();     
     return{
         startVM:startVM,
         checkBoxHandler:checkBoxHandler
     }
 } 
 $(document).ready(function(){   
 master = new masterVM();   
     ko.applyBindings(master);   
 });


 $(document).bind("pageload",function(event,data){
     ko.applyBindings(master);
 }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div>       
            <a href="secondPage.html" data-role="button" >      
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My View Model for Knockout looks like this, here i generate the HTML code and fill the array of checkboxes:

```
var checkBoxVM = function() {
    var cbArray = [ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
    var htmlexampleCB = ko.observable();
    init();
    function init() {
        $.each(cbArray, function(index, item) {
            var htmlCB = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"exampleCB\" id=\""
                    + item + "\" value=\"" + item + "\">  ";
            var htmlLabel = "<label for=\""+item+"\">"+item+"</label>";
            var html = htmlCB + htmlLabel + "<br />";
            var all = "";
            if (htmlCompanyCB() != null) {
                all = htmlCompanyCB();
            }
                all = all + html;
                htmlCompanyCB(all);
        });
        alert(htmlexampleCB());
    };
    return {
        htmlexampleCB:htmlexampleCB
    };
};
```

secondPage.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="gasPage">
        <div data-role="content">
<!--                <div data-bind="html:companiesHandler.htmlexampleCB"> </div> -->
    <script  type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               var newSet = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="cbGroup"></fieldset>';
               $('.cbDiv').append(newSet);
               var newBox = '<div data-bind="html:checkBoxHandler.htmlexampleCB">';            
               $(".cbGroup").append(newBox);
        });                 
    </script>
                <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class="cbDiv">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="cbGroup">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried several other solutions that i saw here but unfortunately non of them worked for me.

Could someone please give me a hint or tell me what i should do, i don't have any other ideas.

Thanks in advance and i hope that someone can help me.

Comment: if you refresh the page, they get styled?

Comment: Hello, i tried like this     `$(".cbGroup").append(newBox).trigger('create');` and it didn't work, i also tried to refresh the page as i saw on other posts, like this: `function refreshPage() {
   $('#gasPage').page();
   $('#gasPage').page('refresh');
   
  }`  but this also didn't work for me

Comment: I meant if you refresh it manually (f5), does it work?

Comment: Oh, if i do that i loose all the styling from other things i have on that page, buttons and text too, and that is because i load the jquery and jqm in the first page. I think it should be something simple but i don't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

This code after creating the checkboxes dynamically should do it,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Please check the following link to a similar question.

[Dynamic controlgroup and checkboxes unstyled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663033/jquery-mobile-dynamic-checkboxes-lose-style)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this also didn't work for me, i tried the exact way as it is in this example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YKvR3/36/) and for me it didn't work, i have something similar to that example but in addition i use knockoutjs, could it be something from knockoutjs or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: of course i can show the code, but this is not relevant for the checkbox because in welcome VM i set only the languge in witch i want to display some text: `var welcomeVM = function()
 {
   var languageOptions = ko.observableArray(['Romana','English']); 
   var selectedLanguage = ko.observable(languageOptions['English']).publishOn("languageChanged");  
   return{
    languageOptions:languageOptions,
    selectedLanguage: selectedLanguage
   };};`

Comment: I think that i am doing something wrong here(i will split the code in two because it is too long):`var gasCompaniesVM = function() {
 var cbArray = [ "One", "Two", "Three"];
 var htmlexampleCB = ko.observable();
 init();
 function init() {
  $.each(cbArray, function(index, item) {
   var htmlCB = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"exampleCB\" id=\""
     + item + "\" value=\"" + item + "\">  ";`

Comment: `var htmlLabel = "<label for=\""+item+"\">"+item+"</label>";
   var html = htmlCB + htmlLabel + "<br />";
   var all = "";
   if (htmlexampleCB() != null) {
    all = htmlexampleCB(); }
    all = all + html;
    htmlexampleCB(all);});
  $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
  alert(htmlexampleCB());
 }; return {
  htmlexampleCB:htmlexampleCB}; };`

Comment: Or maybe i should do something in the html call: `<div data-bind="html:checkBoxHandler.htmlexampleCB"` I still didn't managed to solve this problem.