# Add checkboxes dynamically to controlgroup

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div id="listado" data-role="listview">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="equiposHechos">

        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript is

```
var identificador=4
$( "#recibo" ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {      
    for(i=0;i<=identificador;i++){      
        $("#equiposHechos").append('<input type="checkbox" name="calificarEquipo'+i+' id="calificarEquipo'+i+'"/>'+'<label for="calificarEquipo'+i+'">Equipo Numero'+(i+1)+'</label>');     
    }
})
```

I want to add checkboxes dynamically ... but I get no styles as I do to recharge them or that they charge me as they should be when they are static

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 or below, you need first to enhance/style markup of checkbox or radio buttons using `.checkboxradio()` and then re-style *controlgroup* by calling `.controlgroup("refresh")`.

```
var identificador = 4;

for (i = 0; i <= identificador; i++) {
  $('<label for="foo' + i + '">Foo' + i + '<input type="checkbox" id="foo' + i + '"/></label>').appendTo("#equiposHechos");
}

/* widgets enhancement */
$("[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
$("#equiposHechos").controlgroup("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Xts8d/)**

Comment: @user3120407 disfruta ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitely ask jquery mobile to restyle them:

Check this:
[Dynamic controlgroup and checkboxes unstyled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663033/jquery-mobile-dynamic-checkboxes-lose-style)

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: I do not work with this :(

Comment: ok, try simply using `$("#equiposHechos").trigger("create");` after creating the inputs