# jQuery Mobile dynamically appending controlgroup radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I cannot for the life of me get Jquery mobile to properly refresh a control group after appending to it dynamically.  I have tried .controlgroup('refresh', true);  .trigger('pagecreate'); and everything else I have found on here.

Please view my jsfiddle demo of the problem.  If you add a radio button it does not format properly in jquery mobile.

The difference between this and [Dynamic controlgroup and checkboxes unstyled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663033/dynamic-controlgroup-and-checkboxes-unstyled) is that mine appends to the control group after an action takes place not when the page is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/msenmyud/7/

```
$( "#addCard" ).click(function() {
    $('<input name="card1" value="ground" type="radio" class="creditCardChoice" id="card4"><label for="card3">Visa Ending in 3333</label>')
    .appendTo("#CCSelection");

    $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
    $('input:radio').checkboxradio('refresh');
    $("[data-role=controlgroup]").enhanceWithin().controlgroup("refresh");
    $('#CCSelection').controlgroup('refresh', true);
    $("#CCSelectionForm").trigger('create');
    $("#saved-credit-cards-page").trigger('pagecreate'); 
});
```

Comment: what is this function `controlgroup` ? never heard of it. The code is a complete mess, like a bomb **exploded** and this is the remains of it.

Comment: the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663033/dynamic-controlgroup-and-checkboxes-unstyled/20692597#20692597). Also, make sure you dont add duplicate ID's `card3` etc.

Comment: That is not the answer, it is a different question and does not work when doing that still.  That only works if you are appending it on the initial page load not after the fact.